# How to create multiple main report with spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jasper-reports

I am using JasperReportsPdfView to generate report in my Spring Boot project.
Currently I have 1 Main report and that main report has many sub report

So, Main Report -> Sub report 1, Sub report 2, etc...

I have `EntityA` that have `Detail` and `Details2`

now I am using JRDataSource to pass the datasource to each sub report like...

```
EntityA entityA = findById(1);
JasperReportsPdfView view = new JasperReportsPdfView();
view.setUrl("classpath:report/main_report.jrxml");
view.setApplicationContext(appContext);

List<Detail> details = entityA.getDetails();
List<Detail2> details2 = entityA.getDetails2();
JRDataSource subReportDetail1Source = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(details);
JRDataSource subReportDetail2Source = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(details2);
final Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("subReportData2", subReportDetail1Source);
params.put("subReportData3", subReportDetail2Source);

return new ModelAndView(view, params);
```

Now I want to create many of this Main Report for each `EntityA`, so I will have list of `EntityA` like

```
List<EntityA> listOfEntityA = findAll();
```

How can I create my Main Report repeated for each EntityA in listOfEntityA?

I have idea to make my current MainReport to become sub report to another MainReport, but I don't know the way to pass the Datasource of each detail1 and detail2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you should not pass the `subReportData2` and `subReportData3` as parameters put define them as fields in the jrxml.

Your main datasource will be

```
new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(istOfEntityA);
```

In you jrxml in you define as fields `Detail` and `Detail2` list, hence the getters on `EntityA`

```
<field name="details" class="java.util.List"/>
<field name="details2" class="java.util.List"/>
```

Then add you subreport to the **detail band** and set the datasource expression as:

```
new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{details})
```

> This way the report will iterate the **detail band** on your **EntityA** list,
>   and call the subreports with the list of **Detail** and **Detail2** of the
>   **EntityA** class as datasource